# why there is no type hint when extends Class in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

like the blow case:
[image]

The `SubClass` property `info` should be assigned to the `BasicClass` property `info`.

I think it's better to have a type hint here.

Is there no type hint because I wrote it the wrong way?

```
interface Info {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

class BaiscClass {
  public info: Info = {
    name: 'a',
    age: 20
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `SubClass` you are declaring the member `info` again, this time with an initialization.

However, subsequent declarations could have a different type (with some restrictions). It seems your IDE does not assume that `info` member is of type `Info` again.

It should work if you re-declare the member again with the same type:

```
class SubClass extends BaseClass {
public info: Info = { 
        age: 10, /* Auto-completion should work here. Note that the type is specified explicitly. */
        name: 'a'
    };
}
```

But because the member is re-declared here, the type could change:

```
interface Info2 extends Info
{
    bla: string;
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
public info: Info2 = { 
    age: 10, /* Auto-completion should work here. Note that the type of "info" is now "Info2". */
    name: 'a',
    bla: 'bla',
};
}
```

You might want to initialize the already declared member in a constructor instead:

```
class SubClass extends BaseClass {
constructor() {
    this.info = { 
        age: 10, /* Auto-completion should work here */
        name: 'a'
    };
}
```

Comment: Note that auto-completion in general depends on the IDE you are using.